# jQuery ajax input field event, options list and setting a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an AJAX function to autocomplete the input field.
The user starts typing in location/city name, and it should trigger an AJAX call for lookup, presenting suggestions of matching city names list to the `input` field. Then the user selects one value and that is set to that `input` field. The below code doesn't even trigger events, I do not see request activity on the network. How to accomplish this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#locationName').keyup(function() { //tried keyup, input
    alert('Ok'); // to test event
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/locationsearch',
      data: {
        'search_text': $('#locationName').val()
      },
      success: searchSuccess,
      dataType: 'text'
    });
  });
});

function searchSuccess(data) {
  locationName.val = 'data';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="locationName" id="locationName">
```

Comment: Works for me with the code snippet. I see the alert and the network request in the dev console after I type a letter in the input box. Are you sure you have jQuery loaded in properly?

Comment: Works for me (event gets triggered and network call observed)

Comment: It is triggering the event here in the snippet, but not on my page.

Comment: Is your page giving you an error message in the console, or any activity on the network page?

Comment: @Light No error messages on the console.

Comment: The edit made on this question has a different jquery link than I am using.

Comment: You might want to look at and consider the jQuery UI Autocomplete: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ Even if you do not choose to use it, it can also give you a lot of hints.

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not seem complete. It's not clear where `locationName` is defined. Consider the following snippet.

```
$(function() {
  function searchLoc(txt) {
    var result = "";
    $.post("/locationsarch", {
      "search_text": txt
    }, function(data) {
      result = data;
    });
    return result;
  }

  $('#locationName').keyup(function() {
    var q = $(this).val();
    if (q.length >= 3) {
      $(this).val(searchLoc(q));
    }
  });
});
```

It's not clear what the resulting data will be, I am assuming text or HTML.

Comment: So locationName is defined `<input type="text" name="locationName" id="locationName">`. The response will be a list of 3 or 5 names of matching the users input, then user clicks one, so either text, or jason.

Comment: @KapishM Not sure how the User will *click one* of the resulting items. Specially if it's fed as text into the text field.

Comment: I want to make the drop-down list to the input field. just like we get suggestions for a google search field. then the user to click one of them to be selected.

Comment: @KapishM then you will want to send JSON data back and then iterate the results to make a List.